# How to avoid memory allocation in Julia?

Tags: julia

Consider the following simple Julia code operating on four complex matrices:

```
n = 400

z = eye(Complex{Float64},n)
id = eye(Complex{Float64},n)
fc = map(x -> rand(Complex{Float64}), id)
cr = map(x -> rand(Complex{Float64}), id)

s = 0.1 + 0.1im

@time for j = 1:n
    for i = 1:n
        z[i,j] = id[i,j] - fc[i,j]^s * cr[i,j]
    end
end
```

The timing shows a few million memory allocations, despite all variables being preallocated:

```
0.072718 seconds (1.12 M allocations: 34.204 MB, 7.22% gc time)
```

How can I avoid all those allocations (and GC)?

Comment: You could rewrite that particular double loop as `id .- fc.^s .* cr` - that'll cut down on allocations.

Comment: there are lots of tips here that might help https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/performance-tips/. But evaluating everything in the global workspace is probably the first thing to have a look at

Comment: @AlexRiley is incorrect: broadcast will not cut allocations when the loop is already devectorized. This is likely due to timing globals.

Comment: @AlexRiley Working with dot operators was the original thing I tried, but this didn't reduce allocations. As the answer below shows, it's global variables that are causing the problem...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the first tips for performant Julia code is to avoid using global variables. This alone can cut the number of allocations by `7` times. If you must use globals, one way to improve their performance is to use `const`. Using `const` prevents change of type but change of value is possible with a warning.

consider this modified code without using functions:

```
const n = 400

z = Array{Complex{Float64}}(n,n)
const id = eye(Complex{Float64},n)
const fc = map(x -> rand(Complex{Float64}), id)
const cr = map(x -> rand(Complex{Float64}), id)

const s = 0.1 + 0.1im

@time for j = 1:n
    for i = 1:n
            z[i,j] = id[i,j] - fc[i,j]^s * cr[i,j]
    end
end
```

The timing shows this result:

```
0.028882 seconds (160.00 k allocations: 4.883 MB)
```

Not only did the number of allocations get `7 times` lower, but also the execution speed is `2.2 times` faster.

Now let's apply the second tip for high performance Julia code; write every thing in functions. Writing the above code into a function `z_mat(n)`:

```
function z_mat(n)
    z  = Array{Complex{Float64}}(n,n)
    id = eye(Complex{Float64},n)
    fc = map(x -> rand(Complex{Float64}), id)
    cr = map(x -> rand(Complex{Float64}), id)

    s = 1.0 + 1.0im

    @time for j = 1:n
        for i = 1:n
            z[i,j] = id[i,j] - fc[i,j]^s * cr[i,j]
        end
    end    
end
```

and running

```
z_mat(40)
  0.000273 seconds
@time z_mat(400)
  0.027273 seconds
  0.032443 seconds (429 allocations: 9.779 MB)
```

That is `2610 times` fewer allocations than the original code for the whole function because the loop alone does zero allocations.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the code samples, globals seem to the culprit. Maybe I should adopt the convention to put the main part of my Julia scripts into a main function...

Comment: Could you explain why using a global causes allocations, and why putting the code inside a function prevents allocations? This behavior isn't obvious from my experience with other languages.

Comment: @JosephGarvin Did you figure out answer to your question? Even I have the same doubt

Comment: @tejas unfortunately I did not I still have no idea

Comment: @JosephGarvin, please have a look here https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#Avoid-global-variables